# Using Leaflet Js, is it possible to know the onclick location of a Marker (ignore anchor point)?

Tags: leaflet, coordinates, markers

I have a marker object that is of a specific height and width, and although it is pointing a single coordinate, the visual representation of the marker spans many pixels. When I click on the visual representation of the marker, I would like to get the underlying map coordinates, but instead I only have access to the single lat/lng coordinate associated with the marker.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On one hand: whenever Leaflet handles a mouse (or touch) event, you can access the original DOM event in the `originalEvent` property of the event.

On the other hand: Given a mouse (or touch) DOM event, Leaflet can magically translate its `clientX` and `clientY` properties into an instance of `L.LatLng` by using [`map.mouseEventToLatLng()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-mouseeventtolatlng).

Combine these two things together, and you can have something like:

```
marker.on('click', function(ev){
  var latlng = map.mouseEventToLatLng(ev.originalEvent);
  console.log(latlng.lat + ', ' + latlng.lng);
});
```

Check Leaflet's documentation for the other conversion methods, as they might prove useful.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I was calculating the latlng based on the pixel count like such:
`var latlng = self._map.containerPointToLatLng([event.originalEvent.clientX - vpWidthDifference, event.originalEvent.clientY - vpHeightDifference]);`

Answer (score 12):

You always can retrieve the coordinates from the Leaflet object map. You can use something like this:

```
map.on('click', function(e){
  var coord = e.latlng;
  var lat = coord.lat;
  var lng = coord.lng;
  console.log("You clicked the map at latitude: " + lat + " and longitude: " + lng);
  });
```

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/2c2793c5b3953ea68e8dd26273f5b93c) you have a working example.

Comment: Hmm, it's odd because I'm running on Cesium v1.25, and whenever I click on the marker, the event object always contains the latlng of the marker anchor point, not the actual coordinate of the map as in your example.

Comment: I have not worked with Cesium, maybe Ivan or on the `cesium` tag can give you a better answer.

Comment: I apologize, I meant to say Leaflet (latest v1.0 rc)

Comment: Have a look at the answer given by Ivan, it will solve your problem. Mine as you said is using a very old Leaflet version (I do not know from where I copy that).